# kubuntu 15.04 background image disappears

Tags: kubuntu, desktop-background

After one of the latest upgrades the background image disapper and the whole background becomes black. Nothing is possible anymore in de Desktop Settings, whatever you change the background will stay black.

When reboot everything seems fixed but after a few minutes black again. Any idea how can this be fixed?

It was a fresh install and not an upgrade from the 14.10.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, I found the problem. In the folder ~/.kde/share/config/ there is a file called kwinrulesrc that needs to be removed.  Just in case rename it and see if that fixes the problem.  If so, it is safe to delete it.